# W-8BEN and 1099

Tags: united-states, india, form-w-8-ben

I have been a non-resident alien for a while with my residence now being in India. Previously, it was the USA. I understand that I am required to submit W-8BEN to my broker. Right now, I don't see any federal tax withholding on my 1099. When the W-8BEN goes to my broker will they stop sending 1099 to the IRS? If yes, what action will they perform instead? Also, I am not sure what I should fill out in the following section of W-8BEN. Can someone help?

Special rates and conditions (if applicable—see instructions): The beneficial owner is claiming the provisions of Article and paragraph
of the treaty identified on line 9 above to claim a  _____ % rate of withholding on (specify type of income):

.
Explain the additional conditions in the Article and paragraph the beneficial owner meets to be eligible for the rate of withholding:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you complete W-8BEN, you will not receive 1099. You will receive 1042-S with Non-resident Alien Withholding. 1042-S can be optionally used in 1040-NR to recover some withholding.

If by "Broker", you mean stock broker (including ETF), then you can claim Article 10 of https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/india.pdf "tax so charged shall not exceed 25 percent of the gross amount of the dividends paid by a United States person"

Comment: Thank you. What about capital gains? What forms will be sent to the IRS apart from 1042-S? And will anything be sent to the Indian tax authorities?

Comment: Under Common Reporting Standard (CRS), of which India is a participant, there is Automatic Exchange Of Information (AEOI). So Capital Gains "figure" will be reported to Indian tax authorities. However, NRA tax withholding BY THE USA only withholds Dividends, but not Capital Gains. All types of forms (or its NRA equivalent, e.g. 1099=1042-S) that you usually receive when you were a resident will be sent to IRS. As your question was focused on Broker, my answer ends here.

Comment: The AEOI is achieved using Line 6 of W-8BEN "Foreign tax identifying number", which is your India tax number.

Comment: @user2371765 I have deleted "which is a Regulated Investment Company" and "Bonds", after reading the treaty again. Both RIC and non-RIC can benefit from Article 10. Bonds is Article 11. "If you receive more than one type of income from a single withholding agent for which you claim different benefits, the withholding agent may, at its option, require you to submit a Form W-8BEN for each different type of income. Generally, a separate Form W-8BEN must be given to each withholding agent."

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. Will only net capital gains be reported to the Indian tax authorities or gross gains? I had a capital loss on the 2018 return which would need to be deducted from the capital gain of 2019.

Comment: @user2371765 When you said "2018 return" do you mean India return? AEOI is only for tax authorities to cross-reference and verify whether what YOU FILLED is true. If India allows carryover of Capital Gain/Loss, then you fill in your form and support it with other documents (e.g. past 1099/1040).

Comment: No. I meant US return. "If India allows carryover of Capital Gain/Loss, then you fill in your form and support it with other documents (e.g. past 1099/1040)"  I am hoping they allow for this because the capital loss is huge. It would be disappointing if I could not use it.

Comment: @user2371765 If you left USA on 1/31/2019, why would you have 2019 USA ECI Capital Gain that is taxable by the USA?

Comment: Because I meet the substantial presence test for 2019 for determining resident status for tax purposes, and so am filing my 2019 US taxes as resident alien. I had some doubt regarding doing this. https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/121596/tax-status-decision But I thought I had grounds for filing as resident alien because I entered the USA on 1/1/2008, and never left until 1/31/2019 but for 2 brief interludes of 15 days each.

Comment: @user2371765 "Do not use Form W-8BEN if you are other U.S. person (including a resident alien individual). You may be a U.S. resident for tax purposes depending on the number of days you are physically present in the United States over a 3-year period." https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw8ben.pdf

Comment: I was resident alien for tax year 2019. Right now, I am a non-resident alien, and for tax year 2020, I will be a non-resident alien, and so will not want 1099 to be sent to IRS. That's why I am submitting W-8BEN. Am I doing anything incorrectly?

Comment: It is correct. But for tax year 2020 and beyond, I cant imagine that USA has any tax on your Capital Gains. If you dont have any ECI and don't need to recover any of the NEC 25% withhed, you dont even have to file 1040-NR for 2020 and beyond.

Comment: Yes, that is correct unless I become resident alien again.

Comment: As a non-resident alien I am not liable to be taxed on my capital gains by the USA. Why then is there line 14 for capital gains on 1040NR? I do have to report capital gains after all. Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: @user2371765: US tax on NRA is divided into two parts, one 'effectively connected' to a US trade or business called Effectively Connected Income (ECI in base64's comment) and the other not. See [pub 519](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#idm140151472910576). The base form 1040NR is only for ECI (note the bold type at the left) and taxable non-ECI income goes on schedule NEC. (Through 2019 NEC was actually page 4 of 1040NR; starting in 2020 it is completely separate.) ...

Comment: ... Non-ECI cap gains are US-taxable if you are actually present in the US for 183 days of the year -- a different test than the substantial presence test, [again see pub 519](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p519#en_US_2021_publink1000222353) -- but it sounds like one you also met, so yes you don't need to report or pay tax on them to US.