# Claiming tax credit on non-US income

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, non-resident, dtaa

For tax year 2019, I meet the substantial presence test and so am planning to file my US taxes as resident alien. I left the USA on 1/31/2019, and started working for an Indian company in July 2019. There was tax deducted at source by this Indian company in 2019. Do I have to show this Indian income on my US tax return? If yes, how do I formally claim credit under the double taxation avoidance agreement for the taxes I paid on this income in India?

I read the following in the dual tax avoidance agreement between India and the USA. https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/india.pdf Does this mean that I don't owe any taxes to the IRS on my Indian wages?

ARTICLE 23
Other Income
 1. Subject to the provisions of paragraph 2, items of income of a resident of a Contracting State,
wherever arising, which are not expressly dealt with in the foregoing Articles of this Convention shall be
taxable only in that Contracting State.